# Clarification on Homomorphism and Automorphism of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I've been struggling to connect some of these concepts for a while now and seem to be confusing myself more than helping myself by continuing to think about them. Could someone confirm or deny my thinking on the following:

> Consider a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$ with
>   $\dim(V)=n$. Since $V\cong F^n$ every linear operator $T:V\rightarrow
>  V$ of full rank can be identified with a matrix in $GL_n(F)$ where if
>   $S,T$ are linear operators on $V$  with full rank then $S\circ T$ is
>   also and for any scalar $c\in F$ we have the matrix $cI\in GL_n(F)$
>   such that $(T)(cv)= T\circ cI (v)=cT(v)$. Then $GL_n(F)\cong Aut(V)$
>   in this setting.
>
> Furthermore, if we have $T:V\rightarrow W$ where $W$ is another finite
>   dim. vectorspace over the field $F$ with the same dimension as $V$, equivalently $n=\dim (W)$, then
>   $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ is equivalent to the ring $\mathcal{M}_n(F)$
>   in the same manner as above (and the inclusion of addition in this new setting). Thus, for $T\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ if $T$ is surjective onto a subspace of $W$, say $U$, we can realize $T$ as the composition of some elements $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(F)$ and $A\in Aut(U)$. If, say, $Aut(U)\cong GL_m(F)$ we may consider the inclusion, $\phi:GL_m(F)\rightarrow \mathcal{M}_n(F)$ of $A\in GL_m(F)$ to $\phi(A)\in \mathcal{M}_n(F)$ where $A$ forms the upper left block of an $n\times n$ matrix and $0$'s elsewhere.
>   Then we have $T=\phi(A)\circ M$.

I think some of the problems I may be having are, first, is any of this right? Secondly, am I ignoring the concept of basis too much (as in, is choosing a basis actually insanely important for the above and I am missing the justification in the claims due to ignorance)? Thanks for your time.

Edit: Changed arguments regarding different dimension in the second paragraph.

Comment: If (in the second part) you mean to restrict to the case $\dim W=\dim V$ only, you should say so explicitly. Don't write "of [dimension] say $n=\dim W$" where $n$ is already used to stand for $\dim V$. At best you did not mean that, at worst you did and you leave it to the reader to figure out that $n$ is not a fresh variable here.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It was at best, and then at worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first claim is right.

The second claimn has problems: $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\cong \mathcal M_{n\times m}(F)$ and even if $n=m$, the ring structure (i.e., multiplication) is a by-product that plays no role in Hom, where we do not hae composition if $V\ne W$ (even though $V\cong W$). On the contrary, addition in $\mathcal M$ makes sense in Hom as well: pointwise addition of maps!

Yes, the isomorphism depend on a choice of basis and picking different bases leads to different isomorphisms (and in the Hom case to different "multiplications"!).

Comment: I changed the second paragraph. However, I think I need to review the isomorphisms between Hom and the matrix ring! (If I can find a reference).